# geog GEOGRAPHY(Point) insert creates syntax error

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Why does this return syntax error at or near "5.1963". The documentation clearly states this is how to do it from my understanding?
http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html#creating-a-geography-table

```
CREATE TABLE sources(
              source_id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
              name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
              shortName VARCHAR(50),country VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
              countryCode VARCHAR(80),
              masl INT NOT NULL,
              long VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
              lat VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
              geog geography(point) NOT NULL,
              valid_from TIMESTAMP,
              county VARCHAR(100),
              countyId INT,
              municipality VARCHAR(100) ,
              municipalityId INT);`
        );
INSERT INTO sources(source_id,name,shortName,country,countryCode,masl,long,lat,geog,valid_from,county,countyId,municipality,municipalityId) values ('SN47230', 'AKRA UNGDOMSSKOLE', 'Akra ','Norge','NO',18,'5.1963','59.2555',POINT(59.2555 5.1963),'2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z','ROGALAND',11,'KARMOY',1149);
```

Comment: `masl` is of type `INT` but you are trying to insert a literal (the number is wrapped in `'`). You will also need to wrap the geometry WKT in `'`!

Comment: Wow it was that simple. Thanks :)